# Can I upgrade from a 10.xx version of ubuntu up to 14.04 LTS without making a CD or a USB installation?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

Can I upgrade from a `10.xx` version of Ubuntu up to `14.04 LTS` without making a `CD` or a `USB` installation?!

Because I have no USB that I want to format right now. And I have no disk big enough to install Ubuntu on. And my `CD-ROM` doesn't have `DVD-ROM`

Comment: Consider using a [net install method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet), as the repos for 10.xx are no longer available

Comment: Thanks! Post that in the main think so I can upvote your comment and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Done And Welcome to SE.  Upvoting my answer will get you on the road to hopefully many points... :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the repos for 10.xx are long gone.  You'll need to perform a [net install, as documented here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet).  You may also be able to use a [Net Install ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/trusty/), as these are small images, much like the method linked to earlier.  I've used these, but always from a clean install, so you may want to back up your files etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, try this way:

1. edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts
2. Run do-release-upgrade in a terminal

if your update-manager doesn't prompt you to upgrade, then check your software sources to see if it is set to "Never". If it is then change the value to "Long Term Support Releases Only".

Comment: You can't use the upgrade/update manager path because the repos for 10.xx and 11.xx have been discontinued.  You can correct me if I'm wrong...